# Can confluent control center web UI be remoted?

Tags: confluent-platform, webui, confluent-control-center

1. I installed confluent-5.1.0 on my **gcp instance** using the following commands:

```
$ curl -O http://packages.confluent.io/archive/5.1/confluent-5.1.0-2.11.tar.gz

$ tar xzvf confluent-5.1.0-2.11.tar.gz

$ confluent-5.1.0/bin/confluent start
```

2. Add line to `/confluent-5.1.0/etc/confluent-control-center/control-center.properties`:

```
confluent.controlcenter.rest.listeners = http://<instance-external-ip>:9021
```

But can't connect to web UI by `http://<instance-external-ip>:9021`

Can some one help me? really appreciate!

Comment: Have you opened 9021 on your GCP firewall config?

Comment: yes i forget open it,thanks u very much! @RobinMoffatt

Comment: Great. I've posted it as an answer if you'd care to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're accessing Confluent Control Center from another machine than the one on which it's hosted, you need to make sure that the firewall it open to allow traffic on the port (default 9021).